# Conditionally flag rows from one group based on data from another group

Tags: conditional-statements, stata

**General problem:** I do not understand how to create a value based on a condition from other groups. I would like to do something like :

```
gen x = cond(cond1==1 & cond2==1, value[**of some other row in a different group**], other_value)
```

**Specific problem:** Given a massive data set that has groups based on `id` that never changes, and a secondary id (`co_id`) that does. Each group has multiple rows that repeat in `time`. Each row has a flag (`is_a`) that indicates a relationship to another group (i.e., `id`) at a certain time. The relationship is indicated by a change to `co_id` so it equals to the other group.

I am trying to do two things:

1. for the flagged rows (`is_a == 1`) find the `id` of the group that the new `co_id` belongs to, and
2. For that other group, flag the year that the connection was made

[image]

In the example above, group `111` was connected to group `222` in time `11` (a connection is made only once). Based on the new `co_id` `'xzx'` I want to indicate the connected `id` of `222` from that time onward. Note that other groups can have that `co_id`, but the correct one is the earliest appearance of that `co_id` in the data (so the one is `222` and not `777`).

For group 222 then I flag that time when the connection was made (`time == 11`).

**The Sample Data:**

```
clear
input int id byte(is_a time) str3 co_id
111 0 10 "abc"
111 0 10 "abc"
111 1 11 "xzx"
111 1 11 "xzx"
111 1 12 "xzx"
111 1 12 "xzx"
222 0 10 "xzx"
222 0 10 "xzx"
222 0 11 "xzx"
222 0 11 "xzx"
222 0 12 "xzx"
222 0 12 "xzx"
777 1 13 "xzx"
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide an example of data people can copy and paste. `ssc inst dataex` lets you provide a small data example as `input` code. How many  people are willing to retype what they see in an image? Also, the term _rows_ is alien to Stata discussions just as _observations_  would be to spreadsheet discussions.

Comment: There's a user-written command called `vlookup` whose approach you might reuse, but it won't work off-the-shelf.

Comment: @NickCox added. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: Thanks for what you have done so far. I think your text and example data still need some surgery before all names and data are consistent. Isn't there an `id_co` needed too?

Comment: @NickCox id_co and is_conn are just examples of how the two new variables I want to create should be, they do not exist in my actual data yet. If there is something else I will of course happily provide

Comment: Sorry, but the problem remains obscure to me. I don't see that the sample data illustrate what you want and I am not minded to guess what else they should they be.  I hope someone else can help you out.

Comment: @NickCox I might some it like this: how can I generate a variable for each observation where is_a==1, so that I can find the id of the group which the co_id belongs to?
At any rate thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the problems was that I was mentally stuck on using `id` as the basis for my grouping operations. Using `co_id` helped here, with some per-sorting:

```
sort co_id time id
by co_id: gen id_co = id[1] if is_a==1
```

Than create a helper variable to check if the `co_id` changed since last `time`:

```
sort id time
by id: gen changed_co_id = cond(co_id[_n]!= co_id[_n-1], 1, 0)
by id: replace changed_co_id = 0 if _n==1
by id time: replace changed_co_id = 1 if changed_co_id[1]==1
```

Now I can create the flag for the other group to indicate when the connection was made:

```
#delimit ;
sort co_id time is_a changed_co_id;
by co_id time: gen is_conn = cond(is_a==0 & 
                         changed_co_id==0 & 
                         is_a[_N]==1 &
                         changed_co_id[_N]==1, 1, 0);
#delimit cr
```

So in order to create the flag we need to sort by `co_id` so we can get both `id`s of the connected groups, by `time` so they can coexist at the time of the connection (and onward) and by `changed_co_id` so we can find the exact `time` in which the connection was made - also, this arrangement makes sure that the newly connected observations appear in the end of each group. Then we flag the observations of the group that initiated the connection: if they are not connected themselves and the last observation is, and newly so.